# Make a bootable CD without ISO file but from a CD

Tags: debian, usb, windows, bootable, data-cd

I have a Windows XP CD which I want to install on a USB Drive. However my own CD drive is broken.   I have a friend's laptop on which Windows 7 is installed (and no idea if it has a CDROM of not).

Please tell me how to do get the ISO from the CDROM to an USB pendrive?

I am using Debian 7

Comment: Sanity check: Are you aware that XP is [end of life since 2009](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows/products/lifecycle)?

Comment: @Hennes i know it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Windows based tool, [ISO to USB](http://www.isotousb.com/). Also you could try using [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to write an ISO file to a USB thumb drive too. UNetbootin runs on all OSes.

*excerpt from UNetbootin website*

> UNetbootin allows you to create bootable Live USB drives for Ubuntu, Fedora, and other Linux distributions without burning a CD. It runs on Windows, Linux, and Mac OS X. You can either let UNetbootin download one of the many distributions supported out-of-the-box for you, or supply your own Linux .iso file if you've already downloaded one or your preferred distribution isn't on the list.

[image: ss of unetbootin]

Comment: @Utkarsh - you can also upvote in addition to accepting. Not sure if you're aware of this or not.